# module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I used Python 3.7.3 and installed tensorflow 2.0.0-alpha0,But there are some problems。such as 
module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer'
Here's all my code

```
import  tensorflow as tf
import  numpy as np

x_data=np.random.rand(1,10).astype(np.float32)
y_data=x_data*0.1+0.3


Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y=Weights*x_data+biases

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y-y_data))

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)          

for step in range(201):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(Weights), sess.run(biases))
```

Answer (score 19):

In TensorFlow 2.0, Keras became the default high-level API, and optimizer functions migrated from `tf.keras.optimizers` into separate API called [tf.optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers). They inherit from Keras class Optimizer. Relevant functions from `tf.train` aren't included into TF 2.0. So to access `GradientDescentOptimizer`, call `tf.optimizers.SGD`

Answer (score 18):

You are using Tensorflow 2.0.
The following code will be helpful:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using TensorFlow version 2.

```
`tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)`
```

The above call is for TensorFlow version 1(ex : 1.15.0).

You can try `pip install tensorflow==1.15.0` to downgrade the TensorFlow and use the code as it is.

Else use the TensorFlow version 2(what you already has) with following call.

```
tf.optimizers.SGD (learning_rate=0.001, lr_decay=0.0, decay_step=100, staircase=False, use_locking=False, name='SGD')
```

Answer (score -1):

For the answer @HoyeolKim gave, it may be needed to add:

```
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

As it is suggested [in this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58952358/10440588)