# module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer' and 'Tensor' object is not callable in Tensorflow 2.0 on python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

**I have one problem with this code in tensorflow 2.0:**

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

w=tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
cost=tf.add( tf.add(w**2,tf.multiply(-10.,w)),25)
#cost=w**2-10*w+25
train= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

------------------------------
Output:
---> 10 train= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer'
```

---

**Then I try to use : tf.optimizers.SGD(0.01).minimize(cost)**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

w=tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
cost=tf.add( tf.add(w**2,tf.multiply(-10.,w)),25)
#cost=w**2-10*w+25

train= tf.optimizers.SGD(0.01).minimize(cost,var_list=[w])



TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

**Please help me I am learning tensorflow.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55682718/module-tensorflow-api-v2-train-has-no-attribute-gradientdescentoptimizer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your error in TF 2.x

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

w=tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
cost=tf.add( tf.add(w**2,tf.multiply(-10.,w)),25)
#cost=w**2-10*w+25
train= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-392f437c54ca> in <module>()
      5 cost=tf.add( tf.add(w**2,tf.multiply(-10.,w)),25)
      6 #cost=w**2-10*w+25
----> 7 train= tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.train' has no attribute 'GradientDescentOptimizer'
```

Inorder to work your code in TF2.x, first you have to disable V2 behavior using `tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()` and replace `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` with `tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`

Working code in below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()

w=tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.float32)
cost=tf.add( tf.add(w**2,tf.multiply(-10.,w)),25)
#cost=w**2-10*w+25
train= tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
```

In TF 2.3, to implements the gradient descent you can use [tf.keras.optimizers.SGD](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/SGD)

Answer (score 0):

you should modify the

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
```

to be

```
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer
```